# Why is method append() used below?

Tags: python, string, list, split, append

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"

num_words_list = []
p = original_str.split()
for i in p:
    yo = len(i)
    num_words_list.append(yo)
print(num_words_list)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? What are you attempting to do? Where did you get the code? Why don't you know what it does? Essentially, what is the context? Why would we know why it does what it does? We can tell you the output, we can find errors but we can't find purpose. 

Please move the actual question into the body of the question and read [ask]

Comment: That's quite a vague question. But in your code you split string and put into array length of each word into array and method `append` is used for adding this length into array of lengths

Comment: It is used to append elements to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, `list` contains elements of any data type. `append` is a method of `list` and used to add a new element to the end of the `list`.

**Syntax**

```
your_list.append(new_element)
```

**Example: adding `4` to the list `l1`**

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l1.append(4)
print(l1)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Again, appending `'a'` to list `l1`**

```
l1.append('a')
print(l1)
```

**New output**
**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'a']
```

In your code, you are appending `num_words_list` by `yo` which contains the length of `i` and `i` contains the length of each word of string `original_str`. In first iteration, `i = 'The'`, `yo = 3` , and `num_words_list = [3]`. Thus, after the full iteration, `num_words_liss` will contains `[3, 5, 5, ... , 4, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

The `append()` method appends an element to the end of the list.

like `list.append(item)`

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox" # your string

num_words_list = [] # your empty list
p = original_str.split() #p now contaons a list of all the words ['The', 'quick'......'lazy', 'fox']
for i in p: # going through p, i is now a word in original_str
    yo = len(i) # yo is the length of i
    num_words_list.append(yo) # you are appending the length of the word to your list [append adds values at the end of the list]
print(num_words_list) # this contains length of each and every word in your list
```

```
[3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 9, 4, 3] # length of every word eg: the is 3, quick is 5...
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do but I don't think this is what the OP is asking. It seems to me the OP wants to know the reason we are adding to the list. Like what is the purpose of it. But due to the vagueness this is saying it's exact why it's used since it does the function but not why it's used in the code (if you get what I'm trying to say) [But it's still correct and I will vote you up]

Comment: @TheGrandJ I agree with you. If OP adds more info I will update accordingly. This is the best I could think in terms of the response based on the limited info.

Comment: Honestly I think in this case the best response is no response until they add more info. But you do you. You are trying to help to the best of your ability and I appreciate that.

Answer (score -1):

It will fill the array with the number of characters for each work in the string "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"

```
output = [3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 9, 4, 3]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is not asking for the output. The OP is asking why is append used.

Comment: And there is no [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) in the code.

Comment: In python a list acts as an array. So you don't have to call him out on that. Lots of people call python lists, arrays. Even I do it sometimes